# Lower central series vs torsion-free lower central series

Tags: gr.group-theory, nilpotent-groups

$\newcommand\tf{\text{tf}}\newcommand\tor{\text{tor}}$Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.  Let $\gamma_k(G)$ denote the $k$th term in the lower central series for $G$, so $\gamma_1(G) = G$ and $\gamma_{k+1}(G) = [\gamma_k(G),G]$ for all $k \geq 1$.

There is also a natural central series that it makes sense to call the "torsion-free lower central series", and is defined inductively as follows.  First, define $\gamma_1^{\tf}(G) = G$.  Now assume that $\gamma_k^{\tf}(G)$ has been defined for some $k \geq 1$.  We then have a finitely generated abelian group
$$V_k = \gamma_k^{\tf}(G) / [G,\gamma_k^{\tf}(G)].$$
Let $V_k^{\tor}$ be the torsion subgroup of $V_k$, and define $\gamma_{k+1}^{\tf}(G)$ to be the pullback of $V_k^{\tor}$ under the projection $\gamma_k^{\tf}(G) \rightarrow V_k$.

It follows from the definitions that each $\gamma_k^{\tf}(G)/\gamma_{k+1}^{\tf}(G)$ is a finitely generated free abelian group.  Moreover, $\gamma_k(G) < \gamma_k^{\tf}(G)$ for all $k$.

**Question**: Is it true that $\gamma_k^{\tf}(G)/\gamma_{k+1}^{\tf}(G)$ and $\gamma_k(G)/\gamma_{k+1}(G)$ have the same rank (i.e. become isomorphic after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$) for all $k$?

Comment: $\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}$Isn't $\gamma_k^{\text{tf}}(G) \otimes_\Z \Q/\gamma_{k + 1}^{\text{tf}}(G) \otimes_\Z \Q$ isomorphic to $\gamma_k(G \otimes_\Z \Q)/\gamma_{k + 1}(G \otimes_\Z \Q)$, so we're comparing the ranks of $\gamma_k(G \otimes_\Z \Q)/\gamma_{k + 1}(G \otimes_\Z \Q)$ and $\gamma_k(G)/\gamma_{k + 1}(G)$?

Comment: Yes. $G/\gamma_k^{\mathrm{tf}(G)}$ is the quotient of $G/\gamma_k(G)$ by its torsion subgroup, which is finite. So they have the same Hirsch rank.

Comment: @YCor: I don't see why that has to be hold.  I agree that the crux of the problem is to prove that $\gamma_k(G)$ is finite-index in $\gamma_k^{tf}(G)$ for all $k$ (you could then use the additivity of Hirsch ranks in extensions), but once you get beyond small $k$ I don't see why the difference is precisely the torsion subgroup of that quotient.

Comment: @LSpice: I only know what $G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ means when $G$ is torsion-free, but I agree that once you kill off the irrelevant torsion subgroup your statement is equivalent to mine.

Comment: $G$ is an Abelian group, hence a $\mathbb Z$-module, and $G \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ means to tensor as $\mathbb Z$-modules.  It does wind up only seeing the torsion-free quotient of $G$.  (For example, $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} n\mathbb Q = n\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q = 0$.)

Comment: @LSpice: $G$ is a nilpotent group, not an abelian group.  I was assuming you were referring to the Malcev completion, which turns a finitely generated torsion-free nilpotent group into an algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}$ in which the original group is the $\mathbb{Z}$-points.

Comment: The Malcev Q-completion can be defined purely group-theoretically (no reference to algebraic groups): I guess it's convenient to denote it $G\otimes Q$. I don't think in any case that $G$ is always meant to be the group of $Z$-points (which by the way would only be meaningful for a group defined over $Z$, not only over $Q$).

Comment: Sorry, you're [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385052/lower-central-series-vs-torsion-free-lower-central-series#comment981100_385052); I don't know what I meant by $G \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$, although it appears that @YCor charitably attached the best possible interpretation to it.

Comment: At least it's quite coherent because at the Lie algebra level, the Malcev K-completion $G\otimes K$ is the same as $(G\otimes Q)\otimes_Q K$ for every field of characteristic zero $K$ (the best known case being $K=R$, since this yields a simply connected nilpotent Lie group).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove this by repeatedly applying the following lemma:

**Lemma**:
Let $G$ be a group and let $A,B \lhd G$ be finitely generated normal subgroups.  Assume that $A$ and
$B$ are commensurable.  Then $[G,A]$ and $[G,B]$ are commensurable and
$$\left(A / [G,A]\right) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \left(B / [G,B]\right) \otimes \mathbb{Q}.$$

At the kth stage of the argument, you've proven that $\gamma_k(G)$ is a finite-index subgroup of $\gamma^{tf}_k(G)$.  Applying the lemma (with $G$ replaced with $G/\gamma_{k+1}(G)$ —- this doesn’t change the relevant subquotients, and since it makes the group finitely generated nilpotent it make all its subgroups finitely generated) we deduce that
the ranks of $\gamma_k(G)/\gamma_{k+1}(G)$ and $\gamma^{tf}(G)/[G,\gamma^{tf}_{k}(G)]$ are the same, and also that $\gamma_{k+1}(G)$ is a finite-index subgroup of $[G,\gamma^{tf}_{k+1}(G)]$.  By construction, the ranks of $\gamma^{tf}(G)/[G,\gamma^{tf}_{k}(G)]$ and $\gamma^{tf}(G)/\gamma^{tf}_{k+1}(G)$ are the same (giving one conclusion!), and also that $\gamma^{tf}_{k+1}(G)$ is commensurable with $[G,\gamma^{tf}_{k}(G)]$ (letting us continue the induction!).

**Proof of lemma**:
We can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is a finite-index subgroup of $B$.  The purported isomorphism can be rewritten as
$$H_1(A;\mathbb{Q})_G \cong H_1(B;\mathbb{Q})_G,$$
where the subscripts indicate that we are taking the $G$-coinvariants.  Since $B/A$ is a finite group, the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence of the extension
$$1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow B/A \rightarrow 1$$
degenerates to show that
$$H_k(B;\mathbb{Q}) \cong H_0(B/A;H_k(A;\mathbb{Q})) = H_k(A;\mathbb{Q})_B \quad \text{for all $k \geq 0$},$$
and taking the $G$-convariants of this gives that
$$H_k(A;\mathbb{Q})_G = \left(H_k(A;\mathbb{Q})_B\right)_G \cong H_k(B;\mathbb{Q})_G \quad \text{for all $k \geq 0$}.$$
The special case $k=1$ of this is what we were supposed to prove.

To see that $[G,A]$ and $[G,B]$ are
commensurable, we will need the **Hirsch index** of a general group $\Gamma$, which is the supremum of the $n$ such that there exists a chain
$$\Gamma_0 < \Gamma_1 < \cdots < \Gamma_n$$
of subgroups of $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_i$ is an infinite-index subgroup of $\Gamma_{i+1}$ for all $0 \leq i < n$ (this is usually only defined for polycyclic groups, but it is not hard to see that this reduces to the usual definition in that case; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000546) answer for more details).

Let $r$ be the common dimension of $\left(A / [G,A]\right) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ and $\left(B / [G,B]\right) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.
Since $A$ is a finite-index normal subgroup of $B$, we can apply the additivity result proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000546) to the short exact sequence
$$1 \longrightarrow A/[G,A] \longrightarrow B/[G,A] \longrightarrow B/A \longrightarrow 1$$
to deduce that
$$h(B/[G,A]) = h(A/[G,A]) + h(B/A) = r + 0 = r.$$
Applying this additivity now to the short exact sequence
$$1 \longrightarrow [G,B]/[G,A] \longrightarrow B/[G,A] \longrightarrow B/[G,B] \longrightarrow 1,$$
we see that
$$r = h(B/[G,A]) = h([G,B]/[G,A]) + h(B/[G,B]) = h([G,B]/[G,A]) + r.$$
It follows that $h([G,B]/[G,A])=0$, so $[G,A]$ is a finite-index subgroup of $[G,B]$, as desired.